# Are there any major parties identifying themselves with Rosa Luxemburg's ideas?

Tags: communism, marxism

It's difficult for me to understand why I'm not hearing about any Luxemburgist parties. The ideas of Rosa Luxemburg seem not to have been refuted like some other branches of communist theory have in many people's opinion. Also, I do know that many consider Luxemburg a martyr for communism, which I would think should attract people to her ideas.

So are there any major parties calling themselves Luxemburgist or embracing Luxemburg's ideology?

Comment: It'd help if you elaborated on what "Luxemburgist" means.

Comment: @DVK I've edited the question to avoid the issue. It would be difficult for me to say what the word means precisely. Now I'm only asking whether there are parties calling themselves Luxemburgist, and there is no need to define "Luxemburgist" in such a question.

Comment: in general most of the social democratic parties would probably demand for themselves the right to represent Rosa Luxemburg ideals, but if they really do is up for debate…

Comment: @ymar I will check the sources and see how much they represent the ideals. As RL did co-found the german communist party they do not necessarily represent all the ideals, but I'll write it up as a correct answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

The Cliffites, being followers of Tony Cliff, namely, those parties influenced by the United Kingdom's *Socialist Workers Party* and last time I checked internationally being the *International Socialist Tendency* even after splits, tend to heavily refer to Luxemburg alongside Trotsky and Cliff obviously.

Wiki cites: "Rosa Luxemburg's conception of the structure of the revolutionary organisation — that they should be built from below up, on a consistently democratic basis — fits the needs of the workers' movement in the advanced countries much more closely than Lenin;'s conception of 1902—4 which was copied and given an added bureaucratic twist by Stalinists the world over." Tony Cliff *Rosa Luxemburg*, London, 1959, p.54 cited in John Callaghan *The Far Left in British Politics* Oxford: Basil Blackwell, 1987, p.95.

They also cite: "Rosa Luxemburg’s place in history", (1959) marxists.org which is pretty effusive.

Comment: Do you have some party literature/program quote displaying said reference? That'd earn my upvote